# .pst displays emails from 2008-2009 only

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

I recently copied a couple .pst files to a hard disk for backup purposes. When I tried to get them back in another computer, Outlook 2007 only shows emails from 2008 and 2009, even it if has emails dating back to 2005.

When I check the .pst size  it shows only 2/3 the size of the actual archive. It happens to both .pst files. I tried importing the .pst into another and opening it directly through menu bar without success.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: They are only 2/3 the size of the backup you made on a hard disk, is that correct? As in you don't have the entire .pst to import?

Comment: No, if I check the size through the properties dialog in Outlook 2007 it shows about 600 MB for a certain pst. However, using Windows Explorer the size seems to be 900 MB. Outlook does not throw any error when trying to import or open the pst file, either. Thanks.